# Force rendering / give the browser a short break?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, browser

lets say you are processing a bunch of data and now that will take some time (in my case I'm accessing multiple resources via AJAX and after receiving them I parse them with RegExp [that parsing is what takes the critical amount of time]).

You also would like to assure 2 things:

- The browser does not feel frozen
- The user has some kind of indicator

I made the following example with jQuery(UI):

JS:

```
  $(function() {
     $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value: 0
     });
     $("#blub").click(function() {
        i = 0;
        while(i < 5000) {
           $("#progressbar").progressbar({
              value: (i / 5000 * 100)
           });
           i++;
        }  
     });
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="progressbar"></div>
<div id="blub">KLICK</div>
```

It seems like the browser is only redrawing its canvas when the while is completely done.
Also the CPU-Usage goes as high as it can.

Is there any way to force breaks or reduce the CPU-Load?

Comment: You could set up an asynchronous loop for the regex parsing of your data.

Comment: while executes as fast as the CPU will allow, using it to update a progressbar is a bad idea.

Comment: Do not use native XHR objects for these methods. Look into leveraging `socket.io` so you're not beating the crap out of the HTTPD threads (what little of them) you're given to use.

Comment: @KevinB Yes you are right. Its maybe a bad example. For my parsing entities I am using jQuerys for-each, but that results in the same problem: it takes as much cpu-time as possible. Thats why I ask

Comment: Just a little remark: I am NOT doing AJAX while iterating/proccessing.. All the data is available in local vars already

Comment: How long does the "RegExp parsing" actually take?

Comment: @Shmiddty that depends on how many elements the user selected. A common scenario has like 10 elements and an execution-time of ~30 seconds (for all elements).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of a `while` loop to render the result after every pass.

Here's the `requestAnimatonFrame` polyfill that falls back to `setTimeout` https://gist.github.com/1579671

And here's how you would replace your `while` loop which does not allow the screen to refresh or render until it is done computing.

```
var i = 0;
animate();
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
         value: (i / 5000 * 100)
    });
    i++;
}
```

Comment: In this example you don't quit the loop. You could, though, with a simple update that only calls the rAF while progress is under 5000, change the 4th line: `i <= 5000 && requestAnimationFrame(animate);`